# How to filter out lines of a command output that occur in a text file?

Tags: shell, pipe, filter

Let's say we have a text file of forbidden lines `forbidden.txt`. What is a short way to filter all lines of a command output that exist in the text file?

```
cat input.txt | exclude-forbidden-lines forbidden.txt | sort
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `grep` like this:

```
$ grep -v -x -F -f forbidden.txt input.txt
```

That long list of options to `grep` means

- `-v` Invert the sense of the match, i.e. look for lines *not* matching.
- `-x` When matching a pattern, require that the pattern matches *the whole line*, i.e. not just anywhere on the line.
- `-F` When matching a pattern, treat it as a *fixed string*, i.e. not as a regular expression.
- `-f` Read patterns from the given file (`forbidden.txt`).

Then pipe that to `sort` or whatever you want to do with it.