# Find common rows of two file

Tags: text-processing

I have two file like this

FILE 1

```
aaaaa  6578
vvvvv  6784
hhhhh  8905
fffff  3245
bbbbb  9876
```

FILE 2

```
hhhhh
bbbbb
```

I would like an output in which there are only the rows of FILE 2 with the relative information present in FILE 1.

Ex. OUTPUT

```
hhhhhh 8905
bbbbbb 9876
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: [How to filter out lines of a command output that occur in a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299462/how-to-filter-out-lines-of-a-command-output-that-occur-in-a-text-file).

Answer (score 0):

The information in FILE 1 are  in 2 different columns, the first with all name (`aaaaa`, `vvvvv`, etc.) and the second with the numerical information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with grep,

```
grep -f file2 file1
hhhhh  8905
bbbbb  9876
```

- `-f` Obtain patterns from FILE.

Comment: The two list must be in the same order?

Comment: @TommasoPalomba looks same as ur expected output.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next } $1 in a' file2 file1
```

When `file2` is read, save each line in array `a`.
When `file1` is read, print the current line if the first field is present in array `a`.