# Visualizing dependencies coded up in makefiles as a graph

Tags: make, gnu-make, plotting, reproducible-build, graphviz

Closely related to [How to display dependencies given in a makefile as a tree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283478/how-to-display-dependencies-given-in-a-makefile-as-a-tree) But the answers given there is not satisfactory (i.e. do not work).

Is there a tool to visualize the Directed Acylic Graphs (DAGs) coded up in standard Makefiles? eg, a shell-script for post-processing through Unix pipes can be an acceptable solution as well (maybe there is a pandoc filter to convert MakeFiles to graphviz or LaTeX).

I don't strictly need a tool that directly typesets this graphical visualisation? Just a common file-format translation of the makefile to a graph-viz file or something similar would suffice.

Comment: You can use `dot` etc. from the `graphviz` package to render DAGs. Transforming a (simple) makefile (explicit direct dependencies) into `dot` format is an exercise in shell programming, or perl etc. (split lines with colon in part before colon and part after colon).

Comment: @dirkt, is there a rudimentary shell script available somewhere? I am really new to *nix programming

Comment: Is your `makefile` recursive: does it include `$(MAKE)` or `make`. If so it will be slow, and generating this graph will be very very hard. (Recursion is usually good, but recursive make is bad.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947821/537980 https://gist.github.com/carlislerainey/9a1e49cb195076165a4f07a683ce05a7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe [makefile2graph](https://github.com/lindenb/makefile2graph) does exactly what the original post author wanted.

For the full installation and usage example:

- Installation (make sure `graphviz` is installed, e.g. with `sudo apt install graphviz` on Debian systems)

```
cd /my/install/dir
git clone https://github.com/lindenb/makefile2graph
cd makefile2graph
make
```

- Generate PNG (no need to use dedicated variable `GDIR` if you add `makefile2graph`'s path to your `PATH` variable)

```
cd /path/to/my/makefile
GDIR=/my/install/dir/makefile2graph
make -Bnd |  ${GDIR}/make2graph | dot -Tpng -o my_graph.png
```